# Rails double-escaping line break

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

I have contstructed a string in Rails:

```
text = 'Example, first line\nExample, second line'
```

so far, so good. I want to print this in a UILabel in my app, so I pass it to my app as JSON. Problem is, Rails spits this string out as

```
{"test":"Example, first line\\nExample, second line"}
```

Note the double escape of the backslash. When iOS interprets this JSON, it rightly strips only one escape and prints the literal \n in the label, rather than interpreting a line break.

How can I get rails to output the text variable as

```
{"test":"Example, first line\nExample, second line"} //note the single escape
```

without being hacky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes prevent escapes.

Try this:

```
text = "Example, first line\nExample, second line"
```